# Change default label font for styling

Tags: qgis, labeling, default-value

Where can I change the default labeling font **"MS Shell Dlg 2"** to a different one?

I don't want to change the default layout font (Options --> Generel Settings)

***Maybe there is a solution to use the global variable, but is there an option to always activate the global variable for fonts?***

The aim is to change the font here:

[image]

**What i've already tried:**

- to find and change the font variable for style labelling

[image]

- to change the default font from windows regedit settings

[image]

Also i found the option to set a default font in Print Composer, that works.
[image]

I use QGIS 2.18.17 LTR and QGIS 3.2.1